# What does "it’ll just be expected of... " mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

“All the teachers are really frustrated,” McDowell said. “We want to meet with parents. We send texts. We call. We try to have conversations. But at the same time, teachers know if they start doing it, **it’ll just be expected of them**.”

Source: https://www.theatlantic.com/education/archive/2017/11/are-parent-teacher-conferences-becoming-obsolete/545900/

Comment: It is expected of you = (people) expect it of you.   Is it **of you** that is causing you difficulty?

Comment: Sorry, @Tᴚoɯɐuo. What does it in my sentence refer to?

Comment: Probably those actions of sending texts and calling. In other words, if teachers start to do more things to get parents to meet with them, then parents will start expecting teachers to text and call.

Comment: @JimReynolds: So you mean  if teachers start to do more things to get parents to meet with them, then parents will not want to attend teacher - parents conferences?

Comment: If teachers start taking extra measures to encourage parent-teacher meetings, parents will come to expect those extra measures; parents won't take the initiative but will come to rely upon such "hand-holding".

Comment: Ah, no. *It* means meeting with parents: Teachers are frustrated because they know it's good for their students and their students' families if teachers meet and communicate with parents. But they probably don't have enough time and energy--and pay--to meet or to communicate with many of them very often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, "It'll just be expected of them" means that teachers are worried that if they do more work than is required of them now, people will come to expect them to do that work in the future, and so they will never be able to stop doing that extra work.

Example: Teacher spends an additional hour meeting with a child's parents even when s/he is not required to be working. Then, later, if the child's parents want to meet with the teacher again, but s/he is not available, they will complain that the teacher is not doing his/her job, even though meeting with them was not required of the teacher to begin with.